# How to get list of all types of associated tables in polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, polymorphic-associations

Suppose, we have table Commentable, which has `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` which is polymorphic in nature. Based on this, how can we get all the list of associated tables / all possible `commentable_type` as per associations?

Comment: Do you know any of the names of the tables which have this column? Some more information on the domain model would be helpful (eq a commentable has many posts / users etc)

Comment: comments belongs_to commentable

Answer (score 2):

Check your models for the `comments` relation. I assume that each commendable model has many `comments`.

```rb
ApplicationRecord.descendants.select { |klass| klass.reflections['comments'] }
```

Or you can select a distinct field `Commentable.distinct(:commentable_type).pluck(:commentable_type)` this query returns an array of types (as strings). Each type is a model name knowing them you can infer table names.

Comment: Without DB query, need list from Active Record methods, need list of all polymorphic associated models name